# How to start as a service on Linux with configuration file

Tags: linux, mongodb, service, configuration, startup

I downloaded MongoDB from the website: https://www.mongodb.org/dl/linux/x86_64-rhel70

The version I downloaded: linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.6.9.tgz

I extracted the downloaded MongoDB package on my CentOS 7 machine and I am able to start Mongod using the binary.

I would like to start MongoDB as a service with a configuration file.

I know the command for the Windows side of things which is:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\mongod.cfg" –install
```

However, I do not know how to accomplish this on a Linux box?

Comment: Like this?  systemctl enable mongod.service

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar That did not work :(

Comment: I mean you want mongo like a Service with systemctl?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar yes, I would like mongodb to be configured like a service such as the example you have given. I would also like to create a configuration file for MongoDB and I would like for the service to be aware of this each time it starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MongoDB doesn't install a service, you can make your own:

1) Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/` called whatever you like, with `.service` as the file extension, like so `MongoDB.service`

2) Write the following into that file:

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Service

[Service]
ExecStart=<Path to binary along with arguments>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3) To start the serivce call `sudo systemctl start <your filename>.service`

Comment: Thank you sir, I have used your method and have successfully started my MongoDB instance as a service with a MongoDB config file

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Centos repository from MongoDB, which will create the required configuration files and systemd scripts.

Just add the repo to Centos:

```
# sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo
```

And the repo information:

```
[mongodb-org-3.6]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc
```

Save the file and then, install:

```
# sudo yum install mongodb-org
```

The configuration file will be in: /etc/mongod.conf

To start the service:

```
# sudo systemctl start mongod
```

You may check the service status:

```
# sudo systemctl status mongod
```

And to enable at startup:

```
# sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

To reload after a config file change:

```
# sudo systemctl reload mongod
```

If you prefer to have the one you downloaded, you may use it somewhat like in Windows, the command would be 'mongod' without the .exe, and you will need to manually create the config file and also a systemd init script.

Comment: Perfect, I will give the yum method a go as it seems like a more simple method. When it comes to installing from yum, do you know if I could install a specific version of MongoDB such as version 3.6.9?

Comment: If it is available in the repo, yes. For this case, you can do a `yum list mongodb-org --show-duplicates` and install the version you want with: `yum install <package_name_with_no_arch>-<version_info>`. For the one you are looking for would be: `yum install mongodb-org.x86_64-3.6.9-1.el7`